# EmberJS Route reuse: edit and create new model

Tags: javascript, ember.js, routes

I'm developing an EmberJS application, and I'm starting to rethink my router mappings.
My application handles `orders`. Each order contains its `details`, `costs` and `dimensions`.
I want every page to be addressable. I started developing with these routes defined:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.route('index', {path : '/'});
    this.route('dashboard');
    this.route('reports');
    this.resource('orders', function() {
        this.route('index', {path : '/'});
        this.resource('order', { path: '/:order_id' }, function(){
          this.route('index', {path : '/'});
          this.route('costs');
          this.route('dimensions');
          this.resource('work', { path: '/works/:work_id' }, function(){
              this.route('index', {path : '/'});
          });
        });
    });
});
```

This was working really good.
I had URL's such as: `/orders` for a list of orders, `/orders/1` for general order details, `/orders/1/costs` and `/orders/dimensions` for order's costs and dimensions respectively.

Although it was working, I've had some extra work because each of the nested `order` routes had a different controller. What I did was `this.modelFor('order');` in the model hook of each nested route. Still, sometimes it felt like I needed a something shared among the routes, since they all use the same model (Order), they just work on different parts of it.

The problems started to appear when I wanted to add the "create order" feature.
I want the URL `/orders/new` to create a new order and start editing it. Similarly, `/orders/new/dimensions` would still apply. In other words, the only thing that changes is the order route `:id` parameter to a static `new` path. The templates and controller I've previously developed could be reused, but I couldn't find any way to do that.

Maybe because 'order' is a resource and not a simple route.
How would you address this problem?

Comment: I'm guessing you would create the route *not* nested under the order resource you defined, then just set the path to /order/new... but I'm not sure, so I'll let some other experienced ember user answer correctly. :-)

Answer (score -1):

Could you do something like:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('orders', function() {
        this.route('new', {path : '/orders/new'});
        ...
    });
});

App.OrdersNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  redirect: function() {
    this.transitionTo('order', App.Order.createRecord());
  }
})
```